# cmake -C pre-load script alternative from CMakePresets.json

Tags: cmake, cmake-language, cmake-presets

When running `cmake --help` one possible option is

```
  -C <initial-cache>           = Pre-load a script to populate the cache.
```

this is great, since the script format specified is the same as `CMakeLists.txt`, allowing for fairly complex logic. If I'm instead invoking `cmake` with all options specified from `CMakePresets.json` file the best I can do is to simply list a `cacheVariables` field, without any dynamic capabilities.

Is there any way to specify a pre-load cache script from *within* a `CMakePresets.json` file?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can use `-C` in addition to presets. The script will be applied after the presets settings.